# ActionFilter exception null when OData filter trows exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, actionfilterattribute, odata-v4

I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` in a WebApi2 project that I use to log requests. The filter is defined in the webapiconfig as a global filter and gets called on request as expected. The problem is that when OData throws an exception( like when calling it with "$filter=a"), the exception in the `OnActionExecuted`is null (When i explicitly thow an Exception it does give the exception as expected).

I also have a RESTier project where the exception gets passed and isn't null. So I know it can be done. And I do use the `System.Web.Http.Filters` namespace so I don't think it's a problem with using the wrong filter.

I tried to make an `ExceptionFilterAttribute`out of the `ActionFilterAttribute` but then it just doesn't get called. I also checked for packageversions not lining up between the project that worked and the one that doesn't but can't seem to find any.

Is this expected behaviour and if so can this be overriden ? Why does it seem to work in the RESTier project ?